# Running docker image in command line: running into errors after copy+pasting code

Tags: macos, docker, command-line, terminal

I'm trying to run the [OpenDroneMap](https://github.com/OpenDroneMap/OpenDroneMap#build-and-run-using-docker) docker image on my MacBook Pro Sierra. I have the image created, however, when I try to run the container I'm running into errors. I'm copying and pasting code from the README.md file so I don't understand what the error is. Is there something wrong with the following code?

```
docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd)/images:/code/images v $(pwd)/odm_orthophoto:/code/odm_orthophoto -v $(pwd)/odm_texturing:/code/odm_texturing my_odm_image
```

It returns "Unable to find image 'v:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: repository v not found: does not exist or no pull access.
See 'docker run --help'."

I've tried modified the command trying to guess at what could be wrong but I'm not familiar enough with command line to figure it out.

Comment: Every volume map must be "-v" not just "v".   Docs are wrong.

Comment: Thank you! I'd mark it as an answer but since it's a comment I can't.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the comment by @user2105103, there is a typo in your docker run command (e.g. the `-v` flag is missing the dash at `v $(pwd)/odm_orthophoto:/code/odm_orthophoto`).

Corrected version is:

`docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd)/images:/code/images -v $(pwd)/odm_orthophoto:/code/odm_orthophoto -v $(pwd)/odm_texturing:/code/odm_texturing my_odm_image`